# Average of cosine waves

Tags: graphing-functions, stochastic-calculus

What looks like the graph of the function $A=E[cos(\omega t)]$, where $E$ means "average" and $\omega$ is a random variable?

Comment: Depends on the distribution of $\omega$.

Comment: You're right Yves..Suppose that the distribution is normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $\omega$ is uniformly distributed in range $[a,b]$, we have

$$E[\cos(\omega t)]=\frac1{b-a}\int_a^b\cos(\omega t)d\omega=\frac{\sin(bt)-\sin(at)}{(b-a)t}.$$

For example, with $a=1,b=3.14$:

[image]

---

In the case of a Gaussian, another Gaussian.

Comment: Thank you Yves..just a question regarding the image - why, at $t = 0$, $E[cos(\omega t)]<1$?

Comment: @LoScrondo: you are right. Typo while entering the equation, but the shape is correct.